# Lightning Activity Composer - Missing Send Email Tab

Tags: lightning, page-layout

My issue is the following: Given the Lighning Activity Composer, where you can log calls, send emails, etc. I can't seem to add the `Send Email` tab.

I have tried to add the Lightning Actions in the layout, but still no results.+

I have also checked [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231044&language=en_US&type=1) documentation, but it hasn't solved it either, and when I access the last url regarding the *missing Email tab*, it returns me an `404` error.

Have any of you encountered this problem? Found any way to add the tab?

Here are some screenshots of my current composer status and the actions in the layout

---

[image: Composer]

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this in a sandbox environment? If so, make sure the Deliverability is set to All Email instead of the default System Email only.

Search for Deliverability in the Setup and change the Access Level: 
[image]

In addition to this, you also need to add the correct Email action to the Page Layout *Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions* section. There are 3 standard Email actions, the correct one is the one that shows up as just *Email*.

[image]

The other email actions are there for transition purposes, according to [this documentation page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249345&type=1), as it was changed in Spring 17.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem! ;)

Comment: Actually, I was reviewing this and it's a mix of your answer and Tiny's one. Would you mind completing it? Thanks.

Comment: But didn't you have those Email actions on the page layout already? I'm referring to your second screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, but there's a third one lol. That is, you have `Email`, `Send Email` and `Send an Email`. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yea, you're right, I just double checked my dev org ;) I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Please add Email in Lightning Experience Actions in the respective layout]

Please add **Email** action in **Lightning Experience Actions** in the respective layout.